# Non-Euclidean Stealth Bomber Problem:

Tags: puzzle, noneuclidean-geometry

This is a fun little riddle I was hoping to share with all of you since I cannot seem to crack it. I was talking to my friend the other day and he mentioned that the US is capable of bombing any point on earth in at least 22 minutes. He estimated the velocity of these bombers to be about 5,000 mph. Whether these figures are true or realistic is somewhat irrelevant to me, whatever the true numbers are, I became curious as to how you would go about calculating the fewest number of planes possible to satisfy these conditions.

Assuming we're not accounting for take-off, landing, or other factors, each plane would be capable of flying anywhere within a circle of radius 1833.33 miles in that time frame. Below is an image I mocked up of what I believe would be the most efficient way to distribute those areas (the planes being at the center of each circle), so that all points can be traversed.

[image]
Now if Kyrie Irving and Shaq were right and the world were a a flat 2d plane, I think the answer would be fairly trivial from here... circumscribe the pattern in the picture above within its bounds... but being that the earth is a sphere, let's just say a perfect sphere with a circumference of 24,901 miles, - I'm not sure how to approach this. I haven't thought much about non-euclidian geometry since high school, and I'm not sure how what I do remember might apply.

Thanks! Interested to hear your ideas!

Comment: I dislike very much this "fun little riddle" about US able to bomb everywhere. At a time where there are so many wars, you should refrain to take such examples.

Comment: It was not my intention to offend, my apologies. I did not consider the implied morbidity and I should have changed the problem to be more sensitive.

Comment: The most efficient covering, as long as the circles are small compared to the size of the earth, is hexagonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you, but with a more realistic speed for the planes the world is flat, or it might as well be.  A more realistic speed for the bombers is $1000$ mph, which is about right for the [US B-58 supersonic bomber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_B-58_Hustler).  That gives a range of only $367$ miles in $22$ minutes.  The curve of the earth will not be important, so just figure the area of $\pi 367^2 \approx 423,000$ square miles per plane compared to an earth surface area of $\pi 24901^2$ and multiply by $4/3$ for overlap of the circles, giving that you need $6138$ planes to cover.

Comment: I think it is more practical to consider the flights of the planes as "planes", because the displacements made by the planes compared to the total surface to be covered of the Earth almost "infinitesimal, tangential and straight" (I say almost, because No, there is an accident!).

Comment: Once you interpret it this way, you have your modeling (I could not tell you if it was right or not, with a "coverage radius" spherical). Maybe modeling it with spherical triangles would be more realistic? Can be...

Would the calculations be complicated or could not a 100% accurate calculation be done? Almost sure.

Comment: @Guillemdlc:  this is quite accurate as long as the radius of the circles is small compared to the radius of the sphere.  I am considering the earth locally flat and computing the area covered by a circle of radius the travel distance.  My $4/3$ factor is for circle overlap in a hexagonal close pack and could be improved a bit.  The next level of improvement is to treat each circle as a spherical cap and compute the area on that basis.  Finally you get into packing effects which can be quite complicated.

Comment: Ok Ross Millikan, I have to leave a moment: in a little while I tell you. Do you want me to try to help you with spherical calculations? I have worked on magnetism and electromagnetism, but the geometric part that I believe is the one that is in this case is extendible to the subject you are referring to.

Comment: Have you thought about incorporating graphs in your honeycomb-coupled circles and with them making paths of minimum length? Do you know how to use the maximum software?

Comment: It is a good idea to take the displacements of airplanes as honeycomb cells, you can see how they can take almost any shape, adapting to trees or roofs of houses .... by extension they could cover the "almost terrestrial sphere" by Complete and form a large sphere (the Earth or modeling: the sphere that results from the summations of all cells or packages of graphs)

Comment: If you want, we can speak in the mail.

Comment: @Guillemdlc:  I can do them, but thought the important point is that they do not need to be done.  You are welcome to add your own answer that incorporates them.  If the circles were a reasonable fraction of the size of the earth they would be needed.  In this case, I am sure the differences will be small.  We have a sizable error range for the size of the circles, so if the answer doesn't change by $25\%$ I would call it no change

Comment: I agree that by taking elements as small compared to land as aircraft displacements are sure to have less than 25% relative error in the calculation, I think it's a good way to tackle the problem.

Comment: Regarding if you want to model the problem with vectors disengagement generated by graphs of minimum path, based on the methods of Djistra, Prim or Kuratowsky among others; You can try to do it with the wmMáxima software